# Convert large byte array into stream C#

Tags: c#, arrays, memorystream

I am trying to convert a byte array into a stream, but my array is larger than 500kb so the rest of my data is cut off.

By searching on google I found the parameter "maxAllowedSize" but I don't know how to use it in this case.

```
byte[] rawData = { };  // < 500kb
Stream binstream = new MemoryStream(rawData);
```

Comment: Why do you believe that there is a 500kB limit for `MemoryStream`?

Comment: `Empty memory streams are resizable, and can be written to and read from.`. What error are you getting?

Comment: You can create a `MemoryStream` object and do `write` in bytes from your array. Say, take X kb each time from your array, do it in a loop. Write method, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.write?view=net-7.0

Comment: `maxAllowedSize`, which is a parameter that limits certain aspects of HTTP requests, has nothing to do with `MemoryStream`. Apparently what you [actually wanted to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) is [How to raise the HTTP request length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71561169/11683).

Answer (score -1):

you can use [MemoryStream.SetLength(Int64 )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.setlength?view=net-7.0) to set maximum length of the MemoryStream:

```
byte[] rawData = { };
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.SetLength(rawData.Length);
ms.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
```